# Esp8266 SD card read from inside of class

Tags: esp8266, c++, sd-card, sd.h

This is now my 3rd attempt at being able to read this sd card from within the Esp8266webserver.
I have made a class WebServer, and would like my sd card to contain my site.
What throws me off, is I am able to access the SD card everywhere with the exception of inside of the
.on callbacks.

I can read from/write to the sd card from Everywhere except for inside of a call back. What makes things even more odd, if I init my sd card using SD.begin(0) inside of the call back, it ALSO fails, That really is confusing. For somereason I can't get SD access inside of the callback.

Any ideas or suggestions would really really be appreciated.

so:

```
void WebServer::handlers(){
  // THIS WORKS!!!!!
  File myFile;
  myFile = SD.open("test.htm");
  if (myFile) {
    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());
    }
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
  // END THIS WORKS!!!!

  server.on("/", [this](){ sayHello(); }); // <- HERE IS WHERE THE TROUBLE STARTS!!!

  server.begin();
}
```

Here is what isn't working, i have removed some code to make it more easy to see:

```
void WebServer::sayHello() { //<- HERE IS THE CALLBACK, This always fails
  File myFile;
  myFile = SD.open("test.htm");
  if (myFile) {
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());
    }
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }

  server.send(200, "text/plain", "hello from esp8266!");
}

void WebServer::handlers(){
  server.on("/", [this](){ sayHello(); }); // <- HERE IS THE SETUP FOR THE CALLBACK (TROUBLE HERE)
  server.begin();
}
```

Here is my full code for reference:

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include "webserver.h"
#include <SD.h>

WebServer::WebServer(int n) { //, Storage*& storage
  ESP8266WebServer server(n);
  if (!SD.begin(0)) {
      Serial.println("SD initialization failed!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("SD initialization success!");
  }
}

void WebServer::sayHello() {
  File myFile;
  myFile = SD.open("test.htm");
  if (myFile) {
    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());
    }
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }

  server.send(200, "text/plain", "hello from esp8266!");
}

void WebServer::handlers(){
  File myFile;
  myFile = SD.open("/test.htm");
  if (myFile) {
    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());
    }
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }


  server.on("/", [this](){ sayHello(); });
  // server.onNotFound(handleNotFound(server));
  server.onNotFound([this, SD]() {
    handleNotFound();
  });
  server.begin();
}

void WebServer::handleClients() {
  server.handleClient();
}

bool WebServer::stream(File dataFile, String dataType) {
  return server.streamFile(dataFile, dataType) != dataFile.size();
}

void WebServer::writeFile(String message) {
  File myFile;
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (myFile) {
    myFile.println(message);
    myFile.close();
  }
}


bool WebServer::loadFromSdCard(String path) {
  Serial.print(path);
  String dataType = "text/plain";
  if (path.endsWith("/")) {
    path += "index.htm";
  }
  if (path.endsWith(".src")) {
    path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("."));
  } else if (path.endsWith(".htm")) {
    dataType = "text/html";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".css")) {
    dataType = "text/css";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".js")) {
    dataType = "application/javascript";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".png")) {
    dataType = "image/png";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".gif")) {
    dataType = "image/gif";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".jpg")) {
    dataType = "image/jpeg";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".ico")) {
    dataType = "image/x-icon";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".xml")) {
    dataType = "text/xml";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".pdf")) {
    dataType = "application/pdf";
  } else if (path.endsWith(".zip")) {
    dataType = "application/zip";
  }
  File dataFile = SD.open(path.c_str());
  if (dataFile.isDirectory()) {
    path += "/index.htm";
    dataType = "text/html";
    dataFile = SD.open(path.c_str());
  }
  if (!dataFile) {
    return false;
  }
  if (server.hasArg("download")) {
    dataType = "application/octet-stream";
  }
  Serial.print(dataFile.size());
  Serial.print("About to send it!");

  while (dataFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(dataFile.read());
    }
  if (server.streamFile(dataFile, dataType) != dataFile.size()) {
    Serial.print("Returned too little data");
  }
  dataFile.close();
  return true;
}

void WebServer::handleNotFound() {
  Serial.print(server.uri());
  if (loadFromSdCard(server.uri())) {
    return;
  }
  String message = "SDCARD Not Detected\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += " NAME:" + server.argName(i) + "\n VALUE:" + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}
```

Also, I want to add, I am seeing this message while compiling. Because I can access the files in other places, I have been ignoring it, but I am seeing:

```
extern SDClass SD;

                ^

C:\Users\kevin\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\libraries\SD\src/SD.h:206:16: note: 'SDClass SD' declared here
```

Comment: When you say it "fails" or "doesn't work", what actually happens?  Is it reading gibberish?  Is it printing the error message?  Is it failing to compile?  What's going on?

Comment: ahh, sorry, The exact thing that happens is the card initializes i get the "SD initialization success!" message from line 10 of the full code. however, I get the error message from the result of myFile = SD.open("/test.htm"); saying: "error opening test.txt"

Comment: Have have `SD.open("test.htm")` and `SD.open("/test.htm")`. Don't know if the slash matters...

Comment: @simSon, I have, I acutally just changed that as It was something I was testing. By moving the read into ANY part of this other than a callback, then it works.... it is just inside of the call back where it fails, I think it has something to do with the callback and I just don't understand this enough to know what is wrong

Comment: You could try to make `void WebServer::sayHello()` a static member if possible